# Evolution calendar error

Tags: gnome, evolution

evolution will not sync with my Google, every time I reinstall the same error apears; that is for authentication with my Gmail, when I put in the correct password it refuses to work, saying that the password I put in was wrong, is there a way I can sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try enabling access to your Google account for so-called 'less secure apps' on https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Then, can you share how you have set up your Gmail account? Did you use the general Online Accounts section on the Ubuntu settings screen or did you configure your Gmail account in Evolution manually without it being mentioned in the Online Accounts list?

In some forum threads about similar issues it is reported that setting up a Google account in Evolution works while going via the Online Accounts setup does not...